# How to fix "Error: Type 'AppExitResponse' not found" in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to run my flutter application but it keeps showing me this errror

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/custom_top_navigator-0.0.4/lib/custom_top_navigator.dart:192:10: Error: Type 'AppExitResponse' not found.
Future didRequestAppExit() {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

i have done flutter clean and co but still the same and also i have tried this method stated on the website below but to no avail

```
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver/didRequestAppExit.html
```

Comment: which version of the package are you using? Have you tried upgrading/ downgrading?

Comment: @ClevinoAlrin i'm using custom_top_navigator: 0.0.4  and i have tried downgrading but to no avail

Comment: you'll either have to wait for a newer version or find another package with same capability...